# Como carregar 10 registros de uma lista Java?

Tags: java

Estou com esse método Java;

```
public String detalhesHistorico() {
    listaHistoricoRemessa = historicoRemessaService.listar(historicoRemessa);
    return "ajax-modal-historico";
}
```

Existe algum método de java que eu possa carregar automaticamente 10 registros do banco?

Estou precisando fazer porque tem mais 120 mil registros e quando vou carrega em tela ele demora muito. Seria somente uma solução paliativa.

Comment: Ela demora muito no processamento *Java* ou em realização da consulta?

Comment: ele realiza uma consulta!

Comment: Bom, aqui na empresa fazemos uma técnica de scroller-infinito.limitando as consultas a 40 registros por página, e trigando no final do scroller uma uma nova consulta por 40 registros. 
Você pode implementar Paginação também .

Comment: @IsaíasdeLimaCoelho como é que eu faço isso?

Comment: Talvez o que preciso é de um método java que seja aplicado na variável **listaHistoricoRemessa**

Comment: Vou postar o código na resposta de como dá pra fazer.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver o seu problema ?

Comment: Caso o problema seja mesmo ja query, não há muito o que fazer além de melhorar a query, ou adotar alguma estratégia de caching (ehcache, redis por exemplo)

Answer (score 1):

```
/ Java code to show the use of limit() function 
import java.util.stream.Stream; 
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.List; 
 class gfg{ 

     // Function to limit the stream upto given range, i.e, 3 
     public static Stream<String> limiting_func(Stream<String> ss, int range){ 
         return ss.limit(range); 
     } 

     // Driver code 
     public static void main(String[] args){ 

         // list to save stream of strings 
         List<String> arr = new ArrayList<>(); 

         arr.add("geeks"); 
         arr.add("for"); 
         arr.add("geeks"); 
         arr.add("computer"); 
         arr.add("science"); 

         Stream<String> str = arr.stream(); 

         // calling function to limit the stream to range 3 
         Stream<String> lm = limiting_func(str,3); 
         lm.forEach(System.out::println); 
     } 
 }
```

Saida :

`geeks
for
geeks`

Link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stream-limit-method-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

Você não vai fazer retornar automaticamente os 10 registros do banco(*para isso, você iria precisar alterar a query*), porém, é possível você capturar esses 10 registros da `lista` completa.

Utilize o [`List<E> subList(int fromIndex,int toIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) para capturar a partição de registros da **lista alvo** da seguinte forma:

```
historicoRemessaService.listar(historicoRemessa).subList(0, 10);
```

Observe também [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313392/selection-of-first-l-items-of-arraylist-of-size-n-l-and-insertion-to-another-a).

Comment: `Sublist()` não vai adiantar porque a lentidão é na consulta. Tem que alterar a query mesmo.

Comment: Valeu o feedback @Piovezan, antes eu tinha perguntado pra ele nos comentários da própria pergunta e o autor falou que realiza sim a consulta, imaginei que o problema estivesse na aplicação.